# 18 C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c undefined reference to `WinMain'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, undefined, dev-c++

i am getting the undefined reference error
[image]

i tried every possible solution on the internet. its not my code my serniors.
i dont know what to do.i tried to resolve this issue its been a week.
i hope someone can help.

Comment: please show a [mre] and the error text as text not an image. At a guess you don't have a `main` function